# What does this line do at the bottom of underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I use a similar line to alert the browser that there is a file for debugging purposes.

```
//# sourceURL=lib_underscore.js
```

But what is this line

```
//# sourceMappingURL=underscore-min.map
```

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Answer (score 2):

That is a source map. This is used for debugging compressed scripts. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map

> JavaScript sources are often combined and minified to make delivering
>   them from the server more efficient. Increasingly, too, JavaScript
>   running in a page is machine-generated, as when compiled from a
>   language like CoffeeScript or TypeScript. By using source maps, the
>   debugger can map the code being executed to the original source files,
>   making debugging much, much easier.